# Chrome img.src security: Image from ASP route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, google-chrome

I have images stored in database tables, I want to get the images and display them inside `<img>` elements, so the `src` attribute points to a MVC route rather than a static file, eg. `<img src="https://localhost:44368/api/Image/Get?guid={guid}" />`
I have created a controller Action which does return the image correctly (ImageView in Fiddler shows it okay):

```cs
[Route("api/Image/Get")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(string guid)
{
    var data = /* Byte[] from database */
    var ms = new MemoryStream(data);
    ms.Position = 0;
    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "image/png");
}
```

But in Chrome the image displays as if it were broken.
The funny thing is that the image displays okay is Edge, so I am wondering if there is some security on Chrome that is blocking the image from displaying?

Attached is a screenshot of two CodePens, the top one on Chrome and the bottom on Edge, as you can see the bottom one shows okay, but the one on Chrome is broken.
Does anyone know why this is?
The API is on a different port than my client, could this be an issue?

How can I get this working on Chrome?

[image: Image from ASP route broken on Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solve this issue.
I have a look at the [MDN Image loading errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Image_loading_errors):

> The specified image's metadata is corrupted in such a way that it's impossible to retrieve its dimensions, and no dimensions were specified in the `<img>` element's attributes.

So I added the following code to load the `byte[]` into an `Image`, then I save the image into a `MemoryStrem`.
It seems a bit long-winded and perhaps over-kill to get the metadata, perhaps there is an easier way?

```cs
var ms = new MemoryStream(data);
var img = Image.FromStream(ms);
ms.Position = 0;
img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
```

I guess Edge is not too fussy about image metadata, I also don't understand why the metadata was not saved with the `byte[]`.
Anywho, I am happy now. :-)